# High concurrency update in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, concurrency, ef-core-2.0

I often have a method which is accessed by a lot of threads trying to update my SQLite database.

For example in my database I want to store how many results were okay and how many were not okay. Every time I get a new result I want to update my database as well. Because this approach would need a lot of locks, I guess, I thought about creating a timer which updates the current values every x seconds. But maybe there is a better way.

That's how I do it:

```
    private Timer _timer;
    private volatile bool _updateThreadStarted;
    private int _ok;
    private int _notOk;

    public async Task AddAsync(Result result)
    {
        if (result.Successful)
        {
            using (var context = CreateContext())
            {
                context.Results.Add(result);
                await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }

            Interlocked.Increment(ref _ok);
        }
        else
        {
            StartUpdateThread();

            Interlocked.Increment(ref _notOk);
        }
    }

    private void StartUpdateThread()
    {
        if (!_updateThreadStarted)
        {
            _updateThreadStarted = true;

            Log.Debug("Database update thread started...");

            _timer = new Timer(async _ =>
            {
                using (var context = CreateContext())
                {
                    var first = await context.Results.FirstAsync();

                    first.Ok = _ok;
                    first.NotOk = _notOk;

                    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }

            }, null, 1000, 1000);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What if just use SQLITE_CONFIG_MULTITHREAD configuration for SQLite? See https://sqlite.org/c3ref/c_config_covering_index_scan.html#sqliteconfigmultithread

Comment: Not really sure what you want to accomplish but you can override the `SaveChanges()` method of your context if you wish. This would give you access to all entities tracked by the context and make sure that you can capture/intercept the data consistently in your app.